# Sort/group individual facets together in ggplot

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

I've created a faceted plot (in ggplot) to illustrate individuals' activity data (so they're faceted by participant id). The [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snJf9.png) that this plot is created from has a long format.

[What I have now: Individuals' data shown in a faceted pie chart plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SF9i.png)

I used the following code to produce the graph above.

```html
ggplot(reshaped_my_data_NAs_selected, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette, labels = c("Social Media", "Messaging", "Browsing", "Other Smartphone","Offline"))+
  theme_void()+
  facet_wrap(~PPNR, ncol = 18)+
  labs(title = "Individuals' Activities Division", fill="Activity") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",legend.box.spacing = unit(0.4, "cm"), plot.title = element_text(margin=margin(0,0,15,0),size=18))
```

Now, for each individual I have a variable, called 'mostused', which indicates which activity is done the most by that participant, and I would like to group the participants (i.e., facets) according to this information. So, participants who used social media the most grouped together, participants who used messaging apps the most also grouped together, etc. Ideally the layout of the figure would remain the same (I quite like how it looks now), but if the layout would change somewhat I can live with that.

I've tried using all sorts of variations of facet_grid as well, but those don't give me the desired result. The closest I've come to what I need is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU0I6.png), but I don't want the individual charts to be spread out like that, and the groups of 'most used activity' still aren't visually grouped together enough.

Cutting out the individual graphs, and rearranging them in Photoshop is my alternative strategy at this moment, but I'd prefer to avoid that. XD

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please use `dput()` or direct dataframe, and post some sample data.

Comment: I'd suggest computing within-group ranks of individuals and then facet_grid based on the rank in the y-direction and then the activity in the x-direction. You can annotate individuals with `geom_text()` instead of using the facet strips to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the code example to go along with my comment under the question.

One option would be to compute within-group ranks and use the ranks and the categories to `facet_grid()` the data. Example with some dummy data below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  individual = rep(1:10, each = 3),
  var = rep(c("apple", "lemon", "banana"), 10),
  prop = c(0.8, 0.1, 0.1,
           0.2, 0.6, 0.2,
           0.2, 0.2, 0.6,
           0.6, 0.2, 0.2,
           0.1, 0.8, 0.1,
           0.1, 0.1, 0.8,
           0.5, 0.25, 0.25,
           0.25, 0.5, 0.25,
           0.25, 0.25, 0.5,
           0.05, 0.9, 0.05)
)


newdf <- df %>% group_by(individual) %>%
  # Find maximum category
  mutate(max = var[which.max(prop)]) %>%
  group_by(max) %>%
  # Rank within groups (is this the best way to rank them? idk)
  mutate(rank = rep.int(rank(prop[which(var == max)]),
                        rle(individual)$length))

ggplot(newdf, aes(1, prop, fill = var)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  geom_text(aes(1, 0.5, label = individual),
            data = newdf[!duplicated(newdf$individual),]) +
  facet_grid(rank ~ max) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = NULL) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>